# matlab based program where output comprises of sum of rows of input

Tags: matlab

Let there be a given matrix as :

```
  c=[5.24 5.19 5.07 4.36;
     5.39 5.44 5.38 5.32;
     5.58 5.12 6.05 4.02]
```

I want to compute the output matrix such that first row of output matrix is as it is first row of c, then second row of output matrix is sum of first two row of c and third row is sum of three rows of c. How to write a matlab code for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Matlab's [cumulative sum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) function:

```
ans = cumsum(c);
```